# What is this marmot-like animal (Tigray, Ethiopia)?

Tags: species-identification

I was searching what are the animals I frequently saw in the north of Ethiopia. I took some bad quality pictures.

For me it looked like a large squirrel, local people called it a rat, and on the internet I find rock hyraxes are quite frequent in the region, but they appear not to have a long tail like the animals I saw, and they don't have the white lateral line

[image: Mammal 1]
[image: Mammal 2]

Comment: It's definitely not a rock hyrax, it looks a lot like a ground squirrel.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like some sort of ground squirrel. Especially in the second picture, the posture is  very characteristic of squirrels in general. The tail also looks very squirrel-like to my eyes. My best guess, without better pictures, is the [Striped Ground Squirrel (*Xerus erythropus*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerus_erythropus).

See the images at:
http://www.flickriver.com/photos/8834404@N02/2902284598/
http://www.flickriver.com/photos/kpzaremba/5094580855/

Comment: The Wikipedia picture isn't particularly good, but searching for _Xerus erythropus_ on Google Images gives some results that look a whole lot like your squirrel.